# How to layout form with labels on left of input textbox with material ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want have form something like this:

For larger screens:

[image]

For smaller screens:

[image]

When I checked the [MUI TextField documentation page](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/), no such example is given. All examples put label [above or inside](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#form-props) textbox:

[image]

**Q1.** Why is it so? Is the layout that I desire is not what is expected by Material  design principle?

So I tried various things:

```
import { FormControl, Grid, Input, InputLabel, TextField } from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Grid container>

      {/* APPROACH 1: <InputLabel> and <TextField> without FormControl */}

      <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={2}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="name-input">First Name: </InputLabel>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={10}>
        <TextField variant="standard" size="small"></TextField>
      </Grid>

      {/* APPROACH 2: <div> and <Input> without FormControl */}

      <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={2}>
        <div> Middle Name: </div>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={10}>
        <Input id="fname-input" />
      </Grid>

      {/* APPROACH 3: <InputLabel> and <Input> with FormControl */}

      <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={2}>
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="lname-input">Last Name: </InputLabel>
        </FormControl>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={10}>
        <FormControl>
          <Input id="lname-input" />
        </FormControl>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-sky-zb2n6q?file=/src/App.js:0-1067)

This renders:

[image]

**Q2.** Note that in above render, wrapping `<InputLabel>` inside `<FormControl>` did not render it.  Why is this so?

Now I have following questions:

**Q3.** What of different approaches should I follow? Or in other words, which of the approaches is inline with react / material ui philosophy? You may decompose this question  In specific, should I use `<div>` vs `<InputLabel>`, `<Input>` vs `<TextField>`? Also, should I use `<FormControl>` or not?

**Q4.** Is there any other preferred / recommended way to achieve what I want, may be an  alternative to `<Grid>` or using `TextField` without splitting it into label and input?

**Edit:**

People voting for close, please at least let me know why you are voting for close, especially if its duplicate with link to existing question. I wanted to know MUI-recommended way to achieve this. I feel what I did isnt really MUI-way, may be as it doesnt look well. But I didnt find any post discussing how we can achieve same layout with MUI.